# Import AndroidStudio project in a new PC keeping the SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, persistence

I have to work in my project from 2 PC, and share it with some partners. In this project we hace a database (SQLite) and when we import the project in a new PC, the database doesn't exist and we have to import it manually. Is there any way to keep the database in the project and if we import it in a new PC, the database will be imported in the project automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I depends on how your app initially creates the database.  If the database is created in code, then when opened on a new PC, or new AVD, or new device, it will recognize that the database is not in the Apps data folders, and will create a new empty database.  If you pre-design and perhaps pre-fill a database, then typically this is added to the project in the Apps Assets folder.  Then, on start-up, the App looks for the database in the data folders, and if not found, it copies it from the Assets folder to the data folder.  In that way, at least you can have a pre-designed database and pre-filled (for lookup tables etc), and since the SQLite database is part of the project structure, it can be copied to different development computers, just by copying the project directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try what you have say!